Multiple Qi transmitter/receiver pairs powering one device
*disclaimer: I'm just a tinkerer and this is more of a hypothetical thought exercise than anything.
I'm planning on adding a usb-c Qi receiver to my keyboard, and I was wondering if it would be possible to use a triple transmitter like this with three receivers like these spaced out across the bottom of the keyboard to power it. Most devices don't have the footprint to even allow multiple receivers but the dimensions of my keyboard got me curious.
